# Mysql - "SELECT field " does fill the memory as "SELECT * " ? - Innodb

Tags: mysql, memory, memory-management, innodb

i was thinking today to this question...

If i have, for example, an innodb table with 20 fields, 100K of rows....how the memory is filled with this two different query:

```
1) SELECT field1, field2, field3 from table where field10 = '1';

2) Select * from table where field10 = '1';
```

Is the memory filled with the whole table in both cases?
How the where is taken in consideration when the innodb_buffer_pool is filled ?

Answer (score 2):

If your `field10` is indexed, InnoDB only needs to read the index to find rows that have that value. Then it needs to read the pages of the table that contain those rows. It doesn't need to read the whole table.

That's the benefit of an index.

If the index also includes `field1`, `field2`, `field3` then InnoDB can skip reading pages from the table. It can get the values it needs from the index alone.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD KEY (field10, field1, field2, field3);
```

Kind of like when you look up someone's name in the phone book and you find their address as an "extra" field. The book isn't sorted by the person's address, but you get it for free.

That's called a *covering index* when you get the columns you need from the index, and the query doesn't have to read the whole row from the table.

You might like my presentation https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really

Comment: Hi Bill, thaks for your presentation, it's very interesting and i'm going to read it all!
Just one more curiosity, the answer is the same also for an update query?
If i've a 2 GB table for example, and i do an update on 10 rows, just that 10 rows are loaded in the buffer right?

Comment: Right. The index helps any query narrow down the "examined rows". Examined rows are loaded into the buffer pool so the SQL conditions in your WHERE clause can be applied for each row.